# i want to make the button visible when clipboard has number when the app starts ( xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

**when i call this method the clipboard value is null**

```
    ****here is the method ****
           async void clip()
        {
            var phoneNum = await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
            if (Clipboard.HasText)
            {

                //btnSaudi.Text = phoneNume;
                Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\d+$");

                if (reg.IsMatch(phoneNum))
                    btnSaudi.IsVisible = true;

            }
        }
```

**but when i use the same code in button click event it works**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DirectM.MainPage"
             Title="DirectN">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="setting" Clicked = "ToolbarItem_Clicked" Order="Secondary" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    

    <StackLayout >
        <StackLayout Padding="20,50,20,10" >
            <Entry x:Name="txtPhone" Keyboard="Telephone" Placeholder="numbe" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Padding="50,50,50,100" >
            <Button x:Name="btnSaudi" Text="ENTER" Clicked="btnSaudi_Clicked" Padding="5,5,5,5" FontSize="Large" />
        </StackLayout>
        
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**and this is the xaml code for the page**

Comment: "when I call this method" - where are you calling it from?

Comment: Can you display the xaml and code behind to give us more information?

Comment: i just edit the question i want to make the button visible if the clipboard value is number

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **onAppearing()** method. This method is called before page become visible.Code like:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            clip();
        }
        async void clip()
        {

            var phoneNum =await Clipboard.GetTextAsync();
            if (Clipboard.HasText)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
                Console.WriteLine(phoneNum);
             
                if (regex.IsMatch(phoneNum))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("match");
                    btnSaudi.IsVisible = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the replay adrain zhu but i tried that before but still the clipboard value returns null

Comment: Did you copy the text before you start your app, cause my app works fine as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Adrain Zhu -MSFT idont know why it didnt work befor but its working now thank you so much

Comment: So, the onAppearing() did work, right?